# Laravel - combining multiple vars into single @foreach

Tags: php, laravel

How can I assign multiple $vars into single @foreach?

For example:

```
@foreach($var1, $var2, $var3 as $data)
      // Code here
@endforeach
```

Edit: I am using Eloquent Model, so if I try and use:

```
@foreach(array_merge($var1, $var2, $var3) as $data)
```

I get array_merge(): Argument #1 must be of type array, Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
as an error.

Comment: foreach is for processing arrays, so make them into an array `@foreach( [$var1, $var2, $var3] as $data)`

Comment: thank you. I tried doing that and I got this error: Property [data_type] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Yes, the type of your three variables matters a lot. If your variables are strings or numbers, you need to create a new array with those values and pass it to the `foreach` loop. If your variables are arrays, you should merge them using the `array_merge()` function. If your variables are collections (in Laravel), you can merge them using the `concat()` method. Please refer to my previous answer for more detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to use `foreach()` on PHP

The `@foreach` in Laravel, just like the `foreach` function in PHP, accepts an array as an argument. It executes the code written inside it for each element of the array. First with the first element of the array, then the second one, and so on.

```php
$myArray = [1, 2, 3];
foreach ($myArray as $element) {
  echo "$" . $element . ", ";
}

/*
Result:
$1, $2, $3,
*/
```

[More information about PHP `foreach()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

#### How to call foreach with more variable

If you have more variables, you can make new array by there.

```php
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;
$var3 = 3;

$myArray = [$var1, $var2, $var3];
foreach ($myArray as $element) {
  echo "$" . $element . ", ";
}

/*
Result:
$1, $2, $3,
*/
```

#### How to call foreach with more `array`

If you have three arrays and you want to merge them, you can use the `array_merge()` function.

```php
$var1 = [1, 2, 3];
$var2 = [4, 5, 6];
$var3 = [7, 8, 9];

$myArray = array_merge($var1, $var2, $var3); // create: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
foreach ($myArray as $element) {
  echo "$" . $element . ", ";
}

/*
Result:
$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9,
*/
```

#### How to call foreach with more `collection` on Laravel

If you're using Laravel and you have collections instead of arrays, you can merge them using the `concat()` method.

```php
$var1 = collect([1, 2, 3]);
$var2 = collect([4, 5, 6]);
$var3 = collect([7, 8, 9]);

$myCollection = $var1->concat($var2)->concat($var3); // create: collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
foreach ($myCollection as $element) {
  echo "$" . $element . ", ";
}

/*
Result:
$1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9,
*/
```

[More information about Laravel Collection Concat](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-concat)

Comment: Thank rozsazoltan! There is one minor issue. Im able to display all the data. However, due to me concatenating the two tables, the data is not displayed all on the same row, but rather as two separate entries

Comment: So if I understand correctly, your variables contain collections representing tables with different columns. You would like to merge the three collections row by row, where the first row of each collection becomes the first row of the resulting table, and so on. Is that correct?

Comment: If so, the [Laravel Collection's `zip()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-zip) function will come to your aid for merging the three collections appropriately. `$var1->zip($var2, $var3)`

Comment: I am displaying data from 2 different tables in laravel. For my sake, Ill call the tables data1 and data2. When I used your above method with concat() with the two queries, it worked. However, data1 was displayed with null data2 values, and a row later, data2 was displayed with null data1 values. For testing purposes I only have one value of data inserted into each table

Comment: Oh, I see. The concat() function creates a new collection with the values, but I assume you also need to keep the columns. Try using the [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-merge) function, which preserves the keys as well!

Comment: That works, but in the example above, data2's field is left blank

Comment: Print out the created merged collection to the screen using the `dd()` function. Examine the differences. It's possible that the merged collection contains different columns, and you have hard-coded the columns to be displayed in your code? Unfortunately, I can only make guesses since I'm not familiar with the columns of `data1` and `data2`, as well as the code that generates your table.